# Can all even numbers be written in this form?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove, or disprove (though I think it to be true), that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2n = (a + 1)(a + 2^{b + 1}) - (c + 1)(c + 2^{d + 1})$.

I have tried induction by manipulating variables to show $2n + 2$ can be obtained, but I can't seem to get an expression for $2n + 2$.

Comment: Have you tried looking at these in binary? That might or might not give you any insight.

Comment: Minor detail: do you consider 0 to be in $\mathbb N$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are explicit values of $a,b,c,d$: 
$$
b=d=1,\quad a=n-2, \quad c=n-3.
$$

Moreover, you can construct values of $a$ and $c$ for arbitrary $b=d$ by the same way.

Comment: If $n\ge 4$ if you define $0\not\in\mathbb N$ or $n\ge 3$ if you define $0\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: @user236182 thank you, forgot about this

Comment: How do you just magically pull this out of thin air exactly? I mean it simply as a curious question, not skepticism.

Comment: @Decaf-Math I assume by trying to get everything but the n's to cancel out, a bit like factorizing

Comment: @Decaf-Math Well, there is more obvious solution when $b=d=0$, and then you realize that result is not affected when you "moving apart" multipliers.